# Ruby - change path with gets

Tags: ruby, string, file, path

I have some problems with this Code. It says, i am using a wrong directory. I want to change the directory path through user-input with "gets" (e_path=gets ; subdirs(epath)).
Any suggestions?

when I use subdirs("/home/etc/") everything works fine.

```
   def subdirs(path)
        subdirs =[]
        folderdirs=[]
        Dir.chdir(path) 
        Dir["*"].each do |x|
            if File.directory? File.join x
                subdirs << x
            else
                folderdirs << x
            end
        end
        puts "____________________________"
        puts "Projekte:\n\n"
        puts subdirs
        puts "____________________________"
        puts "Datein:\n\n"
        puts folderdirs
    end
```

.
.
.

```
puts "\n\nGeben Sie bitte den Pfad ein um ein Workspace zu erstellen:"
e_path=gets
sleep(1)
subdirs(e_path) #Here is the mistake
```

Comment: woow it works!!! why is that? can u explain? thxx

Comment: Max's answer below is correct, gets includes a new line character '\n' at the end of your string, the chomp method removes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gets` includes the line terminator!

```
> gets
Hello, world!
=> "Hello, world!\n"
```

so `Dir.chdir` is trying to change to a directory with a newline in the name. [`chomp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-chomp) gets rid of the trailing line terminator if it exists.